# Refile Gem: Ignore exception when remote_image_url is invalid or doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, refile

We are using [refile](https://github.com/refile/refile) to allow users to upload images to our S3 back end. In addition, we allow users the option of entering a URL to any image on the internet (through the `remote_image_url` property.)

This works fine, as long as the URL entered is pointing to an actual file. However, in the case where there was a mistake in the URL, or some nonsensical input was given, `Refile` will throw the following exception:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - thiswillnotwork):
  app/controllers/my/deals_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  appsignal (0.11.2) lib/appsignal/rack/listener.rb:13:in `call'
```

Is there an option to ignore the cases where the URL entered is invalid (akin to how the `validate_download` option in CarrierWave works) and, ideally, use our fall back image instead?

We have tried mounting the attacher with the `raise_errors` option set to `false`, but with the same results.

Our project uses `Rails 4.2.0` and `Refile 0.5.3`.

**Edit:**

I have confirmed that this exception is a lower level `SystemCallError`, coming from `Kernel.open`, and this exception type is not being rescued by Refile:

```
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError, RuntimeError => error
  raise if error.is_a?(RuntimeError) and error.message !~ /redirection loop/
  @errors = [:download_failed]
  raise if @raise_errors
end
```

I am working on a pull request to refile to fix this.

**Edit 2:**

While working on this, we discovered a [major security issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-security-ann/VIfMO2LvzNs) in `Refile`, enabling a potential attacker to use remote code execution.

> The Refile gem has a feature where a URL will be supplied and the remote file will be uploaded. This can be done by adding a field like `remote_image_url` in a form, where `image` is the name of the attachment. This feature was using open-uri to make this HTTP request without validating the passed URI. An attacker can craft a URI which executes arbitrary shell commands on the host machine.

If you are using `Refile` versions `0.5.0` - `0.5.3`, please upgrade to the latest version. Upgrading will also solve the issue above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the maintainer of `Refile`, this will be fixed in the next iteration. For now, we've created the following, dead simple Ruby class as a work around.

```
# app/services/remote_url.rb
class RemoteUrl
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def valid?
    URI.parse(@url).kind_of?(URI::HTTP)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    false
  end
end
```

and I use it in my controller like so:

```
# app/controllers/model_controller.rb
def model_params
  sanitize_remote_url!
  params.require(:model).permit(:description, ..., :image, :remote_image_url)
end

def sanitize_remote_url!
  params[:model].delete(:remote_image_url) unless RemoteUrl.new(params[:model][:remote_image_url]).valid?
end
```

It is quite a primitive approach, but considering that it will be patched in the next Gem version, I consider this good enough for now.

**Disclaimer:**

Although this offsets some of the vulnerability mentioned in **edit 2** of the original question, an attacker will still be able to do remote code execution, if they can create a folder named `http:` on the file system, as a string like `http:/../etc/passwd` will pass the URL validation, but still read a local file through `Kernel.open`.

The Gem has now been patched (`0.5.4`), and an upgrade is the correct solution.